# Pre Check EJB3.0 feature pack installation on WAS

Tags: installation, websphere, ejb-3.0

Is there a way to know beforehand if EJB3.0 feature pack is installed on my Websphere 6.1 App server? One way to know is to deploy an EJB 3.0 EAR on the WAS and have it complain that feature pack is not installed. But is tehre any way of knowing this beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try creating a profile using the feature pack using a command like:

```
$app_server_root/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName AppSvr01 -templatePath $app_server_root/profileTemplates/EJB3/default.ejb3fep
```

or you could just check if the default.ejb3fep already exists in your installation.

check details at:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp